# alert dialog won't show in my onSwipe method

Tags: android

I want to make so when someone swipe to delete a post, they will be asked if they really want to do that. However, when I swipe my item, no dialog alert is shown.

Press "Ja(yes)" = delete post.

Press "Nej(No)" = do nothing.

Here is the code I'm using:

In my activity:

```
            @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
            alert.setTitle("Ta bort inlägg");
            alert.setMessage("Är du säker på att du vill radera detta inlägg?");
            alert.setPositiveButton("Ja", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    adapter.deletePost(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("Nej", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    
                }
            });
        }
    }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

In my adapter class:

```
    public void deletePost(int position){
    getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
}
```

Comment: You never called `show()` on `alert` ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the alert dailog then show

```
        alert.create();
        alert.show();
```

Add them at the end of your alert dailog

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Only had to change getapplicationcontext to my class and .this in order for it to work as well.